# Solve font cropped only in first line of textbox WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, fonts

I'm using a custom font and I don't know why accented characters such as "ñ" are being cropped at the top.
I have a similiar tool in [this url](http://nekutranslations.es/herramientas/smttool/) and here the font works fine. I know html and css have nothing to do with how WPF works... but anyway...

[image: ñ character is cropped only in first line]

I've tried adding some padding but the result is the same as in the picture. The code of this text box is this:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="translatedDisplaytextBox1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="39"
    Text="{Binding ElementName=traduccionTextBox,Path=Text}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="230"
    Background="{x:Null}"
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
    Foreground="White"
    Panel.ZIndex="2"
    FontFamily="../fuentes/#SMT: Devil Survivor"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    FontSize="16"
    Margin="17,151,0,0"
    TextBlock.LineHeight="13px"
    Padding="1"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Grayscale"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Any idea on why this is happening? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this property:

```
TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
```